# Litecart payment gateway setup

Tags: php, payment-gateway, shopping-cart

Im using Litecart 1.3.3.1 for my shopping cart. I found documentation code 'How to Create a Payment Module', but I do not understand how to do it. Im very new to Litecart. Here is the link.
http://wiki.litecart.net/doku.php?id=how_to_create_a_payment_module

can eanyone explain how to do this.

Comment: What did you try? The link you gave should be a good start?
Try to do it and when you run in to problems that is the time to ask!
Right now the question is way to broad to answer?

Comment: I dn know where to put these files

Comment: Put the file in /includes/modules/payment